# Recuperar valor de Objeto Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Olá,

Estou com dificuldades para recuperar o valor de um Objeto no Firebase Database.

Tenho o seguinte objeto na base:[image: WordDetail]

Queria recuperar no caso o valor de **lastId**(108) para depois, ao salvar na lista de Objetos **Words** ter o ultimo id +1.(Essa informação vai ser usada como uma sequence da base de dados, pois a lista de Words servirá para alimentar um app Android)

Fiz o código abaixo:

```
var words = firebase.database().ref('Words/');
const list = $firebaseArray(words);

$scope.addWord = function (word) {
    var id;
    var wdRef = firebase.database().ref('WordsDetail');
    wdRef.on('value', function(snap) {
        id = snap.val().lastId;
    });

    words.push({
        //idWord: list.length + 1,
        idWord: id,//quero usar o id que recuperei aqui!
        word: word.word,
        description: word.description
    });

    delete $scope.word;
    $scope.wordForm.$setPristine();

}
```

Mas a variável **id** não fica com o valor.

Alguém saberia informar como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, só pra deixar registrado que consegui resolver o problema.

Usei o #scope para controlar a informação **lastId**, carregando assim que a tela é iniciada, e atualizando-a sempre que inserido um novo registro.

O código final ficou assim:

```
var words = firebase.database().ref('Words/');
const list = $firebaseArray(words);

var wdRef = firebase.database().ref('WordsDetail/');

loadLastId();

$scope.addWord = function (word) {
    var id = $scope.lastId;
    words.push({
        idWord: id,
        word: word.word,
        description: word.description
    });

    wdRef.set({
        lastId: id + 1
    });

    loadLastId();

    delete $scope.word;
    $scope.wordForm.$setPristine();

}

function loadLastId() {
    //Preenchendo escopo com o ultimo id
    var wdObj = $firebaseObject(wdRef);

    wdObj.$loaded().then(function() {
        $scope.lastId = wdObj.lastId;
    });
}
```